# Finding the leaf nodes in a tree using adjacency matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, tree

Hey guys I'm currently writing a code that is detecting whether a directed and unweighted graph is tree or not using the adjacency matrix, and also printing the leaf nodes. But I'm not quite happy with my way of solving the problem. So, how can I improve the piece of code that I put below. Thanks in advance.

```
int check_tree(int graph[][MAX], int numberOfNodes, int leafNodes[]){
    int noOfEdges = 0, i, j;
    int visited[numberOfNodes];

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < numberOfNodes; j++)
            if(graph[i][j]) noOfEdges++;


    if(noOfEdges != numberOfNodes - 1) return 0; //in a tree, number of edges are always equal to no. of nodes - 1.

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
        visited[i] = 0; //setting all edges to zero meaning they are not visited.
    visited[0] = 1; //parent node is always 1.

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < numberOfNodes; j++)
            if(graph[i][j]) visited[j]++; //if [i][j] is 1 this means there is an edge an it is visited.

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
        if(visited[i] > 1) return 0; //this means the node is visited more than once which is not the case in a tree.

    //if the code made it this far, we understand that it's a tree. so operations below are for tree.

    int numberOfZeroIndex;

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++){ // this loop detects the leaf nodes from adjacency matrix.
        numberOfZeroIndex = 0; //make it zero in this step so that it will count correctly.
        for(j = 0; j < numberOfNodes; j++){
            if(!(graph[i][j])) numberOfZeroIndex++;
        }
        if(numberOfZeroIndex == numberOfNodes){
            leafNodes[noOfLeafNodes] = i;
            noOfLeafNodes++; //this one is a global variable to keep track of leaf nodes.
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: why are you unhappy about?

Comment: This question may be better suited at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and may receive more feedback if posted there, as the code has no errors and OP only seeks code improvement.